# Is it possible to find modulo of factors of number without factorization?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

% = modulo

n = x * y

b = x % a

c = y % a

n % a = (b * c) % a

Example:

27641 = 131 * 211

5 = 131 % 18

13 = 211 % 18

27641 % 18 = 11 = (5 * 13) % 18

It is easy to check that a number which mod 18 = 11 must be decomposable into factors whose modulos are 1 and 11 and/or 5 and 13 and/or 7 and 17. Is it possible to check which of such pairs matches (or does not match) a given number, without factorization? We're talking about small "a", so I can find potential pairs of mod factors by checking all the options, but factorizing the number may not be as fast, so I'm looking for something else.

Candidates are easy to find, but can they be verified? I figured that since I have a number, I also have factors, but in an implicit form, but multiplying by anything fits 7 and 17 and 5 and 13, and as you can see above, 7 and 17 is a bad pair, I don't know what I can do with this number other than factorize it to see that this number does not have factors that mod 18 give 7 and 17.

I'm talking about the pair itself, so the order of the numbers doesn't matter because I don't want to recreate these factors with the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: 5 mod 12 indicates a 1 mod 6 by 5 mod 6 factorization where their indexes are same parity.